# easy -> When change register address i2c during read operation

Tags: microcontroller, sensors, i2c, cortex-m

My question is very easy (I think).
Let's say I want to read a register, where a result is stored by a sensor.

At which moment do I need to specify the register I want to read?
After the slave address as data?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngFhM.jpg

I don't think so. Because If I previously did a write operation in register 0x1234. And afterwards just do a read (without specifying anything). I will read data from register 0x1234.

Where/when do I need to specify the address of the new register I want to read?

If someone has an answer please let it be known.
Thank you

Comment: I am not referring to *any* part of a data sheet because you haven't said anything about what devices you are using. I was advising *you* to refer to the data sheet(s) which usually tell you how to use the device(s). You haven't asked a question that makes any sense.

Comment: Well, of course I read the datasheet.. But I didn't find anything which really solves the issue I am having. I would like to know how this problem is solved generally. And the picture I linked is from the datasheet

Comment: Another way to formulate my question: When/how do I have to tell which register I want to access for a read operation?

Comment: I found this in less than a minute. http://blog.solutions-cubed.com/sensing-color-with-the-arduino-and-the-tcs34725/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to specify the register you want to read from (if it's not already set) by using a write!

Issue

```
STA
SLA+W
REGISTER
rSTA
SLA+R
DATA
STO
```

That's the most common format. Other less common variants include:

```
STA
SLA+W
READ_REGISTER_ADDRESS
REGISTER
rSTA
SLA+R
DATA
STO
```

I.e. some devices only let you manipulate a pointer to the next data register that is read.

Some devices don't have multiple registers, so you always read from the same register.

Comment: for the common format:
And I don't have to send anything to this register(the one I want to read) during this write process? I just send the register address and thats enough?

Comment: I just noticed something, I am using a controller and for in the libraries I am using there is no repeated start defined. Would a normal stop or finish followed by a normal start work as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work. However, a random register rad is a very basic task, so you should investigate your library. You should also have made a reference to the library in your initial question. Please edit your question in case another person the same question while using the library.